# NSPredicate on NSFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I have a `fetchedResultsController` which is pulling back a number of `User` objects.

I have a one to many relationship with my `User` object, one `User` to many `Site` objects called `sitesToUser`.

I am trying to filter my `[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` quickly, doing:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sitesToUser.isActive == 0"];
NSArray *filt = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

However, the `filt` array never returns any results. It doesn't seem to matter which Entity attribute I use, it never returns any results in 'filt'.

In the above, `isActive` is a `BOOL` saved as an `NSNumber`. Any ideas....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Simply add the ANY function, to return all 'User' objects that match the criteria:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY sitesToUser.isActive == 0"];
```

Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Adding "ANY" to the predicate really seems to work. (Even though it doesn't make much sense to me) maybe it doesn't work for all cases. If somebody still has problems, here's how I solved it in the first place:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sitesToUser.isActive == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

this has worked for me so far.